# Content provider, where are files stored?

Tags: android, file, android-contentprovider

The documentation says "However, if you have a large amount of binary data to add, such as a photograph or a complete song, put a content: URI for the data in the table and call `ContentResolver.openOutputStream()` with the file's URI. **(That causes the content provider to store the data in a file and record the file path in a hidden field of the record.)**".

Is the file stored on internal or external storage? Also does the content provider manage the life of the file, i.e. gets destroyed when the record is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure the file does not get deleted by the content provider, you will need to dispose of it your self. As far as where it is stored - its within the phones content provider. You can query it to retrieve your data once its stored. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) link.